# How could I remove all strings start with # using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a HTML page and I want to remove all the colors that appear in the content.

I want a regex pattern to remove it, for example :

```
input:  this is the page content #ffffff another text

output: this is the page content , another text
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: writing code would be a good start...

Comment: Show us what you have done, and perhaps we can help.

Comment: in vim this works: `%s/\#.*//g`

Comment: i have html page content and i want to remove everything except text , i removed every thing but still appear colors , so i want a regex pattern to remove it @JamesShaw

Comment: If you are trying to play around with HTML, I woudl advise you look at using the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description, you may simply use "#\w+ " or "#\w{6} " (without quotation marks).
But, why there is an extra comma in your given example? Make sure it is just a mistyping or further clarify the description of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
const string regex = @"#\w{6}";
var r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
str = r.Replace(str, "");
```